# Placeholder text not visible on safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, placeholder

I'm applying color to the placeholder using the following css property:

```
.pro_heading input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
}
```

But in Safari it's not visible. [image]

Comment: It seems fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/b4vfx1L5/1/

Comment: I'm implementing it in one of my projects, its not working out                    there.http://client-review.p3hotels.com/arbutus/our-promise-to-you/

Comment: Please check the link in Safari.

Comment: working fine on safari Version 7.0.5 (9537.77.4) on mac

Comment: Its not working on version 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your css

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color:  #777;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:  #777;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color:  #777;
}
```

updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b4vfx1L5/2/

Comment: Its not working in Safari - version 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Comment: I've checked the website you gave me and it doesn't seem a css problem. 
As soon i click in the input (p.e. the name) and then click outside everything will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Yes that fine, as soon as I click on it everything become wright. But its not showing for the first time.